# Why error " No module named 'fcntl' " occurred when using keybind?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to bind hot-keys to function in the python code, so I installed `keybind`, but the error occurs. How to fix it?

The code is

```
    from keybind import KeyBinder
    import time

    def pr():
        print('yeh')

    KeyBinder.activate({'Ctrl-C': pr}, run_thread = True)

    while True:
        print(1)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Then the error is

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Idensas\PycharmProjects\protest\ZEMPTY.py", line 6, in <module>
        KeyBinder.activate({'Ctrl-C':pr},run_thread=True)
      File "C:\Users\Idensas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keybind\binder.py", line 85, in activate
        binder = cls(keymap=keymap, listen_events=listen_events)
      File "C:\Users\Idensas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-        packages\keybind\binder.py", line 63, in __init__
        self.disp = Display()
      File "C:\Users\Idensas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\Xlib\display.py", line 89, in __init__
        self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
      File "C:\Users\Idensas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\Xlib\display.py", line 71, in __init__
        protocol_display.Display.__init__(self, *args, **keys)
      File "C:\Users\Idensas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-        packages\Xlib\protocol\display.py", line 84, in __init__
        name, protocol, host, displayno, screenno = connect.get_display(display)
      File "C:\Users\Idensas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-        packages\Xlib\support\connect.py", line 72, in get_display
        mod = _relative_import(modname)
      File "C:\Users\Idensas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-        packages\Xlib\support\connect.py", line 55, in _relative_import
        return importlib.import_module('..' + modname, __name__)
      File         "C:\Users\Idensas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in         import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\Idensas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-        packages\Xlib\support\unix_connect.py", line 31, in <module>
        import fcntl
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fcntl` is a mechanism on Linux, not Windows systems.

From the `keybind` docs:

`Requires X11 (X Window System). For UNIX-like systems, e.g. Linux.`

https://pypi.org/project/keybind/

You will therefore need a different library for Windows systems.